# How to style a react Link component?

Tags: css, reactjs

When I try to style the Link component, it does not work:

```
Link {
  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

But it does work when I use inline styling

```
<Link style={{padding: '0 30px'}} to="/invoices">Invoices</Link>
```

I use `import './App.css'` and styling normal elements like div does work.

Comment: use `<link>` not `<Link>`

Comment: <Link> is a react component (that's why it starts with a capital)

Comment: Link is finally `a` elemnet in the DOM, it should be `a { padding: 0 30px; }`

Comment: Nice, that works, but what if I want to only style Link components and not all links (a)?

Comment: add a className to link and add CSS to that specific class

Comment: Check browser dev tools to identify the corresponding DOM elements and you can style them as needed. CSS Component ultimately transforms to DOM elements in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link is a react component, which by default isn't directly read/defined in native css styling.
Saying that means only one thing, Links are just anchor tags, and thus you can style/modify them in the css styling sheet using a.
To style all links available on the page (general styling) just add a { general styles..} on top of your sheet.
And then to style each one on their own, make sure its wrapped in a div with a className, and in your styles do it this way:
.divClassNameYouChose a {   custom styles...  }

Answer (score 1):

Provide `className` as a prop to `Link`

```
.link-styles {
  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

```
<Link className={"link-styles"} to="/invoices">
  Invoices
</Link>
```

Comment: Nice, but isn't there a way to change the styling of all Link elements? Or would you then make an own component <Link2> with its own styling and containing the original Link?

Comment: It's just the matter of providing  `className={"link-styles"}` or not

Comment: Looks like code duplication when you have to add 10 times className={"..."}. I would now create a new element Link2 with own styling, but still wondering if you could update the css of the Link component itself, that should be doable somewhere right! ;)

Comment: @ObaApi, it's possible and good to have it as you said. It depends on how the Link is used actually

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this:

1. Using `id` in the component

```
    <Link id="link_Styles" to="/invoices">
          Invoices
    </Link>
```

And css is like

```
#link_Styles { 
   padding: 0 30px;
}
```

2. Using bootstrap inbuilt classes like

```
    <Link className="px-4" to="/invoices"> //px-4 means 24px (1.5rem)
          Invoices
    </Link>
```

3. Using tailwindCSS classes

```
    <Link className="px-7" to="/invoices">  //px-7 means 28px (1.75rem)
          Invoices
    </Link>
```

But for approach 2 & 3, you have to embed their `CDN links` respectively.

4. Using `className` like done by @Amila in first answer